# how to use np.where for 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 3d array and i want to find an array that holds specific values (in this case [1,2,3]) and change it.

```
a3 = np.array([ [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5,
6], [1, 8, 9] ], [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 
6], [1, 8, 9] ], [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 
6], [1, 8, 9] ] ])
```

For example, using np.where

```
np.where(a3 == [1,2,3], [9,9,9], [0,0,0]) 

#Result i want
[[[9 9 9]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]]

[[9 9 9]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]]

[[9 9 9]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]]]
```

But i would get this instead.

```
[[[9 9 9]
[0 0 0]
[9 0 0]]

[[9 9 9]
[0 0 0]
[9 0 0]]

[[9 9 9]
[0 0 0]
[9 0 0]]]
```

I assume it happens because they find each element instead of the subarray.
So how would accomplish what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```py
np.where(np.all(a3 == [1, 2, 3], axis=2, keepdims=True), [9, 9, 9], [0, 0, 0])
```